# How to parameterize a backtick in a MySql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am currently attempting to parameterize my MySql queries in my asp.net application(written in VB).

The query, before parameterization, looks like this, with a variable table name:

```
 Dim mySqlCmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `p" & tableName & "` WHERE StepNum='3'", mySqlConn)
```

This works fine.  However, I'd like to parameterize the table name to protect it from possible attacks.

The new query looks like this:

```
 Dim mySqlCmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE StepNum='3'", mySqlConn)
 mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", "`p" & tableName & "`")
```

The problem seems to be caused by the addwithvalues parsing my backticks incorrectly.  The error message for this query is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''\`ptableName\`' WHERE StepNum = '3'' at line 1

(Note that due to the stackoverflow formatting I have to use two backslashes (\) to get them to display just one here.)

I have tried formatting my query several different ways:

```
 Dim mySqlCmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `@tableName` WHERE StepNum='3'", mySqlConn)
 mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", "p" & tableName)
```

and

```
 Dim mySqlCmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE StepNum='3'", mySqlConn)
 Dim tableNameVar As String = "`p" & tableName & "`"
 mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", tableNameVar)
```

and

```
 Dim mySqlCmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE StepNum='3'", mySqlConn)
 mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", "p" & tableName)
```

with none of them working, and all giving slightly different mysql errors, but the main driving point across all of them seems to be that I need the backticks to indicate a table name and the addwithvalues parsing does not like backticks.

Comment: I believe you won’t be able to do that, in fact the idea of parameters is that you don’t do that. that’s why your tableName is being turned into a string so you can’t inject scripts there. I that would be opened I could add `yourTable Drop Table yourTable` and drop your table

Comment: You cannot use parameters for identifiers. They are only for values. It's just like in VB.  You can't use a variable to specify a variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a parameter for the table name like that.

To make it safe, get the names of the tables from the database, offer those to the user (e.g. in a dropdown) and then validate the table name before inserting it in the string of the query.

Also, [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Hmm, presenting a list of tables from the db to the user is not a viable option here.

And thank you for the addwithvalues article, i wasn't aware that this could cause problems.

Comment: @JonW In that case, in what way is the insertion of the table name in code vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: Actually this specific query is not vulnerable to injection attacks at all.  I'm actually grabbing the tablename variable from a field in MySql right before this, and when it is initially added it is parameterized correctly, 

I just have a new employee going through my code, parameterizing my querys cause I'm too lazy to do so, and it familiarizes him with my project.  So when he asked why it wasn't  working I got curious and posed the question.

Comment: Injection attacks is just one (1) of the reasons to use parameters.  There is also the horrible, hard to read code that results from string concat, code maintainability and accidental data type conversions.  The last one can destroy some DBs as surely as injection attacks.   If the user is even involved at some level you can also use a lookup to convert UI friendly names to table names (`Customers` -- > `tbl_CUST_FOO9`) @JonW